# Find a smooth non-convex function bounded by a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Can you find a function $f \colon (-1,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies

1. $f(0) = 0$,
2. $f(x) \ge (1 - \sqrt{x + 1})^2$,
3. $f$ is not convex on any neighborhood of $0$,
4. $f \in C^k((-1,+\infty))$, with $k \ge 2$ ?

I have been able to come up with the following example: $f(x) = x^2 \left( 1 + \sin^2 \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right)$. This function satisfies conditions 1., 2., and 3. but it is only continuous at $0$ and not $C^2$ or smoother.

Does there even exist such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) := (1-\sqrt{x+1})^2$. If $f$ satisfies your conditions 1., 2. and 4., we have
$$
f''(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0+h)+f(0-h)-2 f(0)}{h^2} \ge \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(0+h)+g(0-h)-2 g(0)}{h^2} = g''(0) = \frac12 > 0.
$$
Thus, $f$ is convex in a neighborhood of $0$. Hence, $f$ violates condition 3.